# swift save multiple manage objects

Tags: swift, nsmanagedobject, saving-data

Having issues saving my manage objects within my code. For some reason when i place data in the first view controller everything works well. For instance

I place new categories such as "Fruits", "Dairy", "Meats". The first view controller takes the data. When I click on the specific item such as "Dairy", and put in "Milk" for items within that section. If I go back to the previous view controller and click on "Meats", I see the same data i put in under "Dairy". How do i properly manage my NSManage objects.

Here is my code below.

import UIKit
import CoreData

class HomeSpecificItemViewController: UIViewController {

```
var selectedItem : [Items] = []


@IBOutlet weak var itemNameTextField: UITextField!



@IBOutlet weak var brandNameTextField: UITextField!



@IBOutlet weak var caloriesTextField: UILabel!


@IBOutlet weak var priceTextField: UILabel!



@IBOutlet weak var amountTextField: UITextField!


@IBOutlet weak var threshHoldNumberField: UITextField!


@IBOutlet weak var stepper: UIStepper!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    stepper.wraps = true

    stepper.autorepeat = true

    stepper.maximumValue = 10

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}




@IBAction func saveButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    let context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
    let itemDescription = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Items", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! Items



    itemDescription.setValue(itemNameTextField.text, forKey: "Items")
    itemDescription.setValue(brandNameTextField.text, forKey: "Items")



    do {
        try context.save()
    }catch _ {

    }


    /*
    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Items")
    let results : [AnyObject]?

    do {
        results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)

    }catch _ {
        results = nil
    }

    if results != nil {

        self.itemDescription = results as! [Items]
    }
```

*/

```
}




@IBAction func cancelPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}






@IBAction func increaseNumberStepper(sender: UIStepper) {


    threshHoldNumberField.text = Int(sender.value).description

}
```

}

Comment: Is your tableview reloaded?

Comment: Could you post your code so we can get a better idea of what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a specific view controller for each category? If so, what you have to do is add predicates to your more specific view controllers.

Something like:

```
var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Food")
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "category == %@", "Meat")

meats = try! context.executeFetchRequest(request)
```

This would return an array of all `Food` objects whose `category` atribute holds the string `"Meat"`.

Answer (score 0):

I was saving my data to core data without properly declaring the manage context and without assigning the text labels to the core data object.

issue resolved!